# Lazy loaded routes won't show up on route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two routes that I lazy load. Currently when I change route by f.e. using `history.push('/')` the former route disappears, but the new one won't show up (after reloading it'll show up). How so?

```
import React, {Suspense, lazy} from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import './modules/Header/Header.scss';
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./modules/Footer/Footer";

const LandingPage = lazy(() => import('./modules/LandingPage/LandingPage'))
const Dashboard = lazy(() => import('./modules/Dashboard/Dashboard'))

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Suspense fallback={<div/>}>

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={LandingPage}/>
                    <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
                </Switch>

            </Suspense>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Inside of index.js I initialized Router:

```
...

import {Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Router history={history}>
            <App/>
        </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend react-loadable for code splitting dynamic imports.

With react-loadable your code should be like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import './modules/Header/Header.scss';
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./modules/Footer/Footer";

import Loadable from 'react-loadable'

const LoadableLandingPage = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./modules/LandingPage/LandingPage'),
    loading() {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    },
})

const LoadableDashboard = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./modules/Dashboard/Dashboard'),
    loading() {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    },
})



function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={LoadableLandingPage}/>
                <Route path='/dashboard' component={LoadableDashboard}/>
            </Switch>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Same problem consists, the other route will only be loaded on reload, but not on route change - the former route disappears, but the new one wont appear.